# java how to set the text of a label in a JFRAME (parent form) , from a JPANEL(child form)

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jframe, jpanel

This is better i think. why label text is not changing?
The main class is in NewJFrame form

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        public NewJFrame() {
            initComponents();
            NewJPanel jpanel = new NewJPanel();
            anotherPanel.add(jpanel);
         //there is also a label in this frame outside of the anotherPanel
        }
    }
```

This is a JPanel form. i am adding this jpanel into NewJFrame (anotherPanel)

```
public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
        public NewJFrame newJFrame;
            public NewJPanel() {
                initComponents();
                this.setSize(200, 200);
        //there is a button here
            }
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                this.newJFrame = newJFrame;
      newJFrame.jLabel1.setText("Need To change the text from here"); // this is not working, text is not changing
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that in your JPanel code, you're creating a new JFrame object that is completely different from the JFrame that is being displayed, here:

```
public NewJPanel() {
 NewJFrame newfr = NewJFrame();  // *** here ***
```

and so calling the NewJFrame methods or setting its fields will have no visible effect on the visualized GUI.

To solve this, you must call methods on a viable reference to the class who's behavior you want to change, here the NewJFrame class. So you must pass in a reference of this class into  your NewJPanel class, perhaps in its constructor so that the NewJPanel class can call methods on the NewJFrame object that is actually being displayed.

For example:

```
public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {  
  private NewJFrame newJFrame;

  // pass in the current displayed NewJFrame reference when calling this constructor
  public NewJPanel(NewJFrame newJFrame) {
    this.newJFrame = newJFrame;
    newJFrame.setMyLabelText("qqqqqq");
  }          
}
```

Then in the NewJFrame class, you pass a reference to `this`, the visualized JFrame object:

```
public NewJFrame() {
  NewJPanel pane= new NewJPanel(this);
```

The bottom line here is don't even think of these guys as or JFrames or JPanels. Just think of them as objects of classes that need to communicate with each other, and this is usually done through public methods. It's no different for GUI's as it is for non-GUI programs.

Comment: @loukaskoniotis: I have given you the solution! Please review that first, and attempt to implement it. Also, never post code in a comment as it is unreadable. Please edit your original post and post code there.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info! but i tried what u said and it still not working.... i have update the code and i added a button to make the change. still the label text is not changing.

Comment: @loukaskoniotis: you are still creating a new NewJFrame inside of your JPanel class. Again, please don't do this. Again, pass in the reference in the JPanel's constructor as I recommended above. Until you do this, you will not solve this.

Comment: ok, look up again.i have update the code us you are saying and i am getting Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException when i hit the button

Comment: @loukas: You are not yet doing what I say. Please read my entire post again. You first need to pass a viable reference into the class, for example in the constructor as I actually show you in the code above.

Comment: Your JPanel constructor still doesnt accept reference to JFrame instance. Look carefully in Hovercraft's answer how to pass the reference from JFrame using 'this' to the JPanel constructor. This line should be in the constructor not in actionPerformed - this.newJFrame = newJFrame;